# Run Logic When User Presses "x" in Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to run some logic when the user presses the "x" in the upper right hand corner of my Windows Form application. There is a logout button but I am confident the user will not always logout. So I will run same logic on the click of "x". I have the following, but it will not hit the breakpoint.

**Code**

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //sql server queries to be executed
    lblSucessMessage.Text = "Succesfully logged out";
}
```

Comment: Did you add this method to the form's `FormClosing` event?

Comment: I don't believe so.. I just added it as an existing method in my Form1 class. Where can that be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach handler to event. This can be done in constructor (as well as in designer of your form);

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{    
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
   }

   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       //sql server queries to be executed
       lblSucessMessage.Text = "Succesfully logged out";
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to go to the Form's properties, find the FormClosed event, and double click on it. It will add the event to the Form and create the corresponding method. Move your code to the newly created method and delete the method you wrote.

That should get you rolling.

Comment: I clicked the form in designer view, navigated to right hand property pane and did not see then FormClosed event listed... any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have the form itself selected and not a control on it, first off.

Comment: The long way is to go to the Form.Designer.cs file and add the even handler manually, this is the code directly from my current project:            


this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosed);

Answer (score 1):

You have 'closed' and 'closing' events, that you can just implement in the constructor. Example:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Closed += (sender, args) =>
     {
       /*Handle event*/
     };
     Closing += (snd, args) =>
     {
       /*Handle event*/
     };
}
```